# Netflix/Conductor prints too many dynomite related logs

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, netflix, netflix-conductor

I'm using Netflix/Conductor with `docker-compose`. When I set the `docker-compose.yml` file up I see too many lines related to dynomite. I think it consumes a lot of memory and slows down my system. I have to mention that Conductor doesn't use the official `Netflix/Dynomite` image but it uses `v1r3n/dynomite` image. Is there any way to reduce the amount of logs related to it? I know it's possible with grep to reduce logs, but I want to change the log level or use the official dynomite image. My current docker-file (by the way its the official version in Netflix/Conductor github repo):

```
# Docker compose for netflix conductor + elasticsearch + dynomite
version: '2'
services:
  conductor-server:
    environment:
      - CONFIG_PROP=config.properties
    image: conductor:server
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - elasticsearch:es
      - dynomite:dyno1

  conductor-ui:
    environment:
      - WF_SERVER=http://conductor-server:8080/api/
    image: conductor:ui
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/ui/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    links:
      - conductor-server

  dynomite:
    image: v1r3n/dynomite

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4
```

Comment: I couldn't add a tag for netflix-dynomite or dynomite

Comment: "I have to mention that Conductor doesn't use the official Netflix/Dynomite image but it uses v1r3n/dynomite image." This is a bit worrying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can expose stats/admin port 22222:

`dynomite:
        image: v1r3n/dynomite
        ports:
            - 22222:22222`

and after that use admin api to decrease or increase log level and so on ( as described in https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/wiki/REST )

to decrease log level following API muse be called :

`curl -s http://localhost:22222/logleveldown`

Comment: This works! But I still need to manually do this. Is there a way to decrease the log while I'm setting the `docker-compose.yml` file up?

Comment: I agree with @ksadjad! Did you end up finding a better solution to your problem?